# Create a menu component with options in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im new in react redux, im trying to succeed creating this component with options inside:

[wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ka8v.jpg)

but my aproach is this, with buttons inside this modal:[what i have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qYMu.jpg)

I'm trying to do all without importing libraries, and i dont know if there is a more suitable solution.

This is my code for this "modal card option"

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { withTheme } from 'styled-components';
    const CardWrapper = styled.article`
      padding: 20px;
      width: 320px;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    `;

    // Define a header for card wrapper
    const CardHeader = styled.header`
      padding-bottom: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      color: #212121;
    `;

    // Define h1 for card heading
    const CardHeading = styled.h1`
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #a3a3a3;
      text-align: left;
    `;


    // Define div for card body
    const CardBody = styled.div`
      padding-bottom: 24px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
    `;


    const CardComponent = () => (
      <CardWrapper>
        <CardBody>
          <CardHeader>
            <CardHeading>Moneda Extranjera</CardHeading>
          </CardHeader>
          <FlatButton light>USD Dolares</FlatButton>
          <FlatButton light>CH$ Pesos</FlatButton>
          <FlatButton light>R$ Reales</FlatButton>
        </CardBody>
        <CardBody>
          <CardHeader>
            <CardHeading>Otros</CardHeading>
          </CardHeader>
          <FlatButton light>Transferencia</FlatButton>
          <FlatButton light>Cheque</FlatButton>
        </CardBody>
      </CardWrapper>
    );

export default CardComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap). For your specific example - [ListGroup](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/listgroup/).

There are many other libraries. I find this one easy to use.